# Plurals usage in sentence

Tags: grammatical-number

I always get confused when I have to use plurals in sentences like the following:

```
Please specify circuits and boards wirings identifiers.
```

Is it correct to add the "s" at the end of all of them?
Or is there some overuse here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the only plural you need to use is the final one:

> Please specify circuit and board wiring identifiers.

As this refers to identifiers for wiring on both circuits and boards.